# How can i pass the variable through groovy script for helm install

Tags: kubernetes, groovy, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I Have created the groovy script and added some blocks of code in the groovy script, But I need to understand that how can I pass the following arguments for variables to helm install:

1. appAuthors
2. appVersion
3. appID

I know these arguments wrong, but I need the correct those arguments for a helm. Can anyone suggest to me which arguments I need to pass the variable?

```
helmInstall name: "$(DEPLOYMENT_NAME)-build",

        namespace: "account-opening-api",
        chart: 'base-app-build', 
        version: env.BASE_APP_BUILD_VERSION,
        appAuthors: env.APP_AUTHORS, 
        appVersion: env.APP_VERSION,
        appID: env.APP_ID, 
        values: .helm/${SERVICE_NAME}/build-values.yaml',
    args: [
        "--set output.imagestream.tag=${IMAGE_TAG}",
        "--set output.imagestream.name=${DEPLOYMENT_N
              ]
```

Comment: What are those specific settings (they are not normal Helm options)?  Where does the `helmInstall` command come from?  My guess is that you want to include those settings in the `build-values.yaml` file too (the `output` settings also probably) but it's a little hard to tell without more detail.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I just want to know what option we can use rather than appAutthors, appVersion,appID. Is there any argument available in helm that we can use our custom variable value.?

Comment: The `helm install -f` option would pass a YAML (or JSON) file of settings into the chart, or the `helm install --set` option can set a specific key; these could be referenced with _e.g._ `.Values.output.imagestream.tag` inside the chart.  It's not clear how these standard Helm options relate to the Groovy wrapper you're showing here, though.